# Facebook connect and authentication of custom PHP application

Tags: php, facebook

I have my own php application that have restricted part, which an be only used by authenticated users. Following instructions [from](http://www.pakt.com/pakt/?id=ce00f49ed79e17aa&t=How_to_add_Facebook_Connect_to_your_website_using_Javascript) I did manage to create FB application and to enable login by email used for FB login.

ok, but, what to do next, and how to join my web application and FB login application system? i guess that somehow i have to get information from facebook application and to... do what?

can you please give me some ideas how to finish this one? thank you in advance!

Comment: (to ambiguous to fully answer but...) if you have a user table in your db, then use the email acquired from there facebook as there username, then use the same password for all your fb users(make it long and secure)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tutorial that you followed implements the client side flow. It means that every thing is done in the browser of the user and your web app cannot retrieve (easily) some data from Facebook.

You have to implement the server side flow. A good and easy way to do that is to use the Facebook PHP SDK ([see on github](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk)). So you will have something like :

```
require "facebook.php";
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => YOUR_APP_ID,
    'secret' => YOUR_APP_SECRET,
));

$user = $facebook->getUser();
```

If the user is logged in, then `$user` is his Facebook ID. You then have to check if you have a valid access token by making an API call :

- If it does not raise any exception, then you have a valid access token
- If it does, then you have to re-authenticate the user.

Here :

```
if ($user) {
  try {
    $facebook->api('/me');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    $user = null;
  }
}
```

You need then to display the login or logout link :

```
<?php if ($user): ?>
    <a href="<?php echo $facebook->getLogoutUrl() ?>">Logout of Facebook</a>
<?php else: ?>
    <a href="<?php echo $facebook->getLoginUrl() ?>">Login with Facebook</a>
<?php endif ?>
```

When the user is logged in and you have a valid access token, you can make API calls to get data from Facebook :

```
$user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
```

You may want to check the [example page of the Facebook PHP SDK](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk/blob/master/examples/example.php) which is well documented.

Hope that helps.

Comment: could you please update the links in your answer. they are dead now.